# Avoiding Copy of Boost::Asio::Buffer and General Buffer Confusion

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, boost-asio

Here is an excerpt from the Connection class from the boost::asio tutorials at http://www.gamedev.net/blog/950/entry-2249317-a-guide-to-getting-started-with-boostasio/?pg=10.

```
class Connection : public boost::enable_shared_from_this< Connection >
{
    friend class Acceptor;
    friend class Hive;

private:
    boost::shared_ptr< Hive > m_hive;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket m_socket;
    boost::asio::strand m_io_strand;
    boost::asio::deadline_timer m_timer;
    boost::posix_time::ptime m_last_time;
    std::vector< uint8_t > m_recv_buffer;
    std::list< int32_t > m_pending_recvs;**
    std::list< std::vector< uint8_t > > m_pending_sends;
    int32_t m_receive_buffer_size;
    int32_t m_timer_interval;
    volatile uint32_t m_error_state;
```

To write data to this tcp socket, you pass and copy a vector to the pending_sends member list.  Later, a boost::asio::buffer is created using the vector as a parameter.

I would like to edit this class to be able to write the contents of 1 buffer to many connections without needing to copy the underlying memory for each socket.  Would the following steps be a reasonable way of doing that?

- Start by creating a shared_ptr to some kind of data structure that can be a basis for a buffer (std::streambuf, std::string, std::vector)
- Copy the shared_ptr to each connection class that I want to write its contents to.
- Create a boost::asio::buffer object using the shared_ptr
- Call socket.async_write

In particular, I am extremely hazy about the concept of a buffer / stream.  I don't know exactly why I should create a boost::asio::buffer from 1 type of object instead of another.  Is there particular reason why the author of this code has chosen `std::vector ?  If I am getting my data by calling a serialize function that writes to an ostream, would it be best to use a std::streambuf?  I'd appreciate any resources that help clear up the concept of a buffer.

Comment: _"Is there particular reason why the author of this code has chosen `std::vector`?"_ - Maybe because `std::vector` is part of the C++ Standard Library and is likely to be immediately available and without any dependency on any third party library.

Comment: A const buffer holds nothing more than a pointer and a size. So you can cheaply copy those. The shared_ptr would just be there to reference-count the underlying buffer data.

Comment: `asio::buffer` does not copy data, it's purely a wrapper and you are responsible for managing the life time of the data. In this case, the whole `shared_ptr` stuff is pointless, simply wrap the underlying `vector` with an `asio::buffer` and pass this to the write operations.